# How do I change the storage class of existing persistent volumes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I have a bunch of standard PVs bound to PVCs in Kubernetes running in Google Kubernetes Engine. I want to change their storage class to SSD. How do I achieve that?

Comment: do we speak about https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#gce-pd `type` field?

Comment: That's right @Nick

Comment: Stash can be helpful to backup PVCs and restore the data to new PVCs with the desired storage class. https://www.objectif-libre.com/en/blog/2020/01/10/kubernetes-backup-stateful-apps/

Answer (score 13):

No it's not possible to change the storage class of an existing PVC.You will have to create a new PVC with desired storage class and then delete the existing one.

Answer (score 4):

If I understood you correctly, you would like to change a type for your PVs, and the question is not  "if" but "where".

The relations between PVC, PV and StorageClass is very [simple](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistentvolumeclaims).

PVC is just request for a storage of particular **type** (specified under `storageClassName` ) and **size** (that is listed in PV) .

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
spec:
...
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 8Gi
  storageClassName: slow
```

PV has `storageClassName` in `spec:` .

```
kind: PersistentVolume
...
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
...
  storageClassName: slow
```

The `storageClass` has `type` .

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: slow
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
  fstype: ext4
  replication-type: none

# type: pd-standard or pd-ssd. Default: pd-standard
```

Is it the info you've been looking for?

Comment: I want to change the `storageClassName` of the PV. @Nick

Comment: in order for storage to be provisioned properly, the storage class needs to changed on PV and PVC. Unfortunately it's not possible to change it on existing PVC. It'll be needed to create a new PVC and migrate data then.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can't just change the storage class name, but it IS possible to re-provision a new drive with the same contents and - crucially - with the same drive name. There are two ways:

1. Create a brand new deployment/statefulset, and then blue/green or repoint the traffic across. Depending on your current infrastructure, this might result in an outage. Especially if you need the keep the data in-sync whilst the migration is happening, this can be quite painful.
2. Recreate the existing PV/PVC. This is neater and easier in some ways, but it's also gonna cause an outage fer'sure.

Regarding 2, the high level steps are:

- backup the existing GKE disk
- spin down the pods and detach the PV/PVC from the GKE disk (this is where the outage begins)
- create the new GKE disk of the right size & type
- copy the data from the old disk to the new
- configure a PV + PVC manifest for the new GKE disk & apply it - you should see the GKE disk successfully attached to the PV & PVC. (this is where the outage ends)
- spin *up* the pods again and watch as your application comes up with the old data, in the new storage class & size.

**IF** you're using a stateful set with a dynamic volume template, you're going to need to delete the entire stateful set and reapply it as the dynamic volume template part of the stateful set spec is immutable.

You can find more detailed instructions here: https://blog.srcinnovations.com.au/2023/11/23/changing-kubernetes-pvc-storage-class-and-downsizing-them-at-the-same-time/