# Change GKE storage class without losing content

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, terraform-provider-gcp, storage-class-specifier

I've inherited a terraform/helm based GKE with a set of deployments and services in production environment. All of them use the default storage class as PVC.

I would like to switch to a more robust way of storage (default retain or even Filestore+NFS). I was wondering if there is a way to switch the storage class to the newer ones *without* loosing or manually move the content from the oldest default volumes. This eventually using terraform and updating the Helm charts for consistency.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Hello. Do I understand correctly that your terraform/helm resources are creating your PVC with default options (`reclaimPolicy: Delete`) and you want to change it to `reclaimPolicy: Retain`? Please have a look here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-pv-reclaim-policy/ . You could also create a `storageClass` that will have this `reclaimPolicy` set to `Retain` by default. Do you already have data that cannot be lost and you want to copy it to Filestore?

Comment: Yes, but I'm quite sure that updating my tf scripts (with another storage class) i'm going to loose the content of the persistent storage, am I right? I was just wondering if a storage can change its class _in place_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You cannot change your `StorageClass` to a different one and expect the data to not be lost.**

Think about your `StorageClass` as a way to tell Kubernetes what are the available storage options for use. You could have a `NFS` storage and `Ceph` storage. Changing the `StorageClass` for a `PVC` that stores your data will not transfer the data to a new location.

**You won't be even able to change most of the parameters in already created `StorageClasses` and `PVC's`.**

You can read more about it by following below links:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Storage classes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/)*
- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: How to: Persistent Volumes: ssd-pd](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/ssd-pd)*
- *[Stackoverflow.com: How do I change the storage class of existing persistent volumes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61187909/12257134)*
- *[Cloud.google.com: Compute: Disks: Create snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots)* - for your disks backup

---

> I was wondering if there is a way to switch the storage class to the newer ones without loosing *(the data I assume)*

As said previously it's not possible to just change the `StorageClass` to a different one.

> or manually move the content from the oldest default volumes.

Yes, this is possible and there are several ways to do it. The exact situation you are facing is unknown to us (what exact resources are you having, the data on it, the way they are deployed etc.).

Please take a look on below resources:

- *[Medium.com: Migrate Kubernetes volume data](https://medium.com/@icheko/migrate-kubernetes-volume-data-f34f71ce5aa5)* - you could use this guide to mount old volume and a new one (Filestore PVC?) to copy the contents of old volume to a new one.
- *[Cloud.google.com: Filestore: Accessing fileshares](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/accessing-fileshares)* - this is the guide to create PVC from Filestore.
- *[Velero.io](https://velero.io/)*

You can use above example with copying files between `PVC's` to create a `Job` that will do it automatically.

> This eventually using terraform and updating the helm charts for consistency.

If you mean to create your resources supporting new storage you configured, it's possible. You will need to modify your existing resources/create new resources to support new storages. Please make sure you tested your solution before using it on production.

Comment: many tnx, your answer is perfect and the resources you linked were crystal clear. Although I was limiting my question from just a subset of two of all the available storage classes choices: the default storage and the default retain.

Comment: If you are thinking about changing the `ReclaimPolicy` of your `PVC's`, please take a look here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-pv-reclaim-policy/